# mysql join with the same table without duplicates

Tags: mysql, join, self-join

I have a table `instructors` with the following strcture/data:

```
-----------------
|id  | name     |
-----------------
|1   | saad     |
|2   | imran    |
-----------------
```

I want to do a join with the same table without returning duplicate results.

If i do a simple join, the query returns 4 rows `[saad, saad], [saad, imran], [imran, imran], [imran, saad]`.

And if I add a where clause it returns 2 rows `[saad, imran], [imran, saad]`.

However, I only want to return 1 row, (i.e. if `[saad, imran]` was already returned, the query shouldn't return `[imran, saad]`).

Here's my query thus far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    i1.name AS name1,
    i2.name AS name2
FROM 
    instructors i1, instructors i2
WHERE
    i1.name != i2.name
ORDER BY
    name1, name2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   i1.name AS name1,
   i2.name AS name2
FROM 
   instructors i1, instructors i2
WHERE
   i1.id < i2.id
ORDER BY
   name1, name2
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for my two rows but will this work regardless of the number of rows in the table?

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help. I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me!

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    i1.name AS name1,
    i2.name AS name2
FROM 
    instructors i1, instructors i2
WHERE
    i1.name > i2.name
ORDER BY
    name1, name2
```